# Opening program in Unity Dash opens about:blank tab in browser?

Tags: unity, 13.04, unity-dash

I'm not sure what's causing it, but it's a right pain in the neck.

Every time I open a program from the dash, it doesn't matter what it is it opens a new tab in the browser. This shows the about:blank page.

What's causing this and how can I stop it?

Comment: Use **Dash** / Applications to search for one of these apps. Drag it to the Unity panel, and click on it. *Does this have the same issue, and does the issue also affect your existing launch icons?*

Comment: It happens with 12.10 as well

Answer (score 7):

Found solution to the bug.  The issue resides in online accounts needing authorization.  Another user posted online that once they logged in and authorized their Google Accounts, the problem stopped.

I have decided to turn off google integration because despite authorizing access, google periodically makes you re-authorize access.  I hope this prevents the issue from comming back.

Now I know how to fix.